# list of countries into uipickerview swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3, uipickerview

I googled how to find the list of the countries and trying to implement into `PickerView`, but I am stuck at this point where I try to do `countries.count` it gives me an error saying:

> cannot convert return expression of type 'int' to return type 'string'
>   any suggestions?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerValue: UIPickerView!

    let countries = NSLocale.isoCountryCodes.map { (code:String) -> String in
        let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
        return NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US").displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return countries.count
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return array count in method `numberOfRowsInComponent` and in the `titleForRow` you need to return array object, show that it will show in picker.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return countries.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return countries[row]
}
```